# facebook graph api error You are using an incompatible web browser

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-scraping

i'm trying to display my facebook group wall on my external web page and it gives me the error message..

> You are using an incompatible web browser.
>   Sorry, we're not cool enough to support your browser. Please keep it real with one of the following browsers:

```
*
  Mozilla Firefox
*
  Google Chrome
*
  Safari
*
  Microsoft Internet Explorer
```

My code for checking the returned content is as follows..

echo(file_get_contents('http://www.facebook.com/groups/GazelleAB/'));

Can someone please tell me what else i need to get this working. I'm using PHP.

sowi guys i'm using Firefox 3.6.15

Comment: send a user-agent string also via your code

Comment: Sorry, we're not cool enough to answer your question ;)
I second @Jamies's question....

Comment: Obviously facebook considers screenscraping uncool.

Comment: I edited the question, sory about that.

Comment: @Filburt, I've noticed that, so how do you suggest i do to get my groups information on my site.

Comment: @Dee-M : I second (and upvote) Jamie's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sugest you use the [Facebook Graph API for Groups](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/) rather than trying to scrape the data you want.

Comment: I think i'm heading to the right direction, just need to find out if accessing a closed group and open group via the graph api differs, what parameters should i pass to access the closed group?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that this seems to be a case of your firewall, whatever kind you are running, trying to protect you from some transaction that is required by Facebook. For Symantec Endpoint, for example, go to Network Threat Protection -> Options -> Change Settings and under Stealth Settings, remove checks from all 3 boxes.  If it's a different firewall, look for some setting that might be filtering out what Facebook needs. (Symantec, at least, does warn you in the Settings box that enabling these settings may interfere with using some websites.)